# Android Bluetooth Low Energy - custom Service is not getting Scan Callbacks

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an unusual problem. I have developed a simple app to use BTLE to discover iBeacons. I have created 2 variants of the application. The first has all the code in a MainActivity, and runs the BTLE methods using a callback. This works well and I get results back from my beacon. All good.

The second has all the same code, but I've put it into a service, which I can call from my MainActivity. The service works but when the Bluetooth startScan is fired off it never gets to the Scan Callback. This is strange as it's using the SAME code as the first application. It gets stranger. I took my code to another developer and put the application with the service onto his PC and then ran it attached to his phone. It worked perfectly with the callback working as expected. I dont understand whats happening.

We are using the same version of Android 6.01, have the correct permissions for BT and Location.

I've erased my Android Nexus 5 and reinstalled Android 6.01, and yet the same behaviour is occurring. I'm stumped. It's not the code, it works on another machine & phone.

Has anyone got any pointers as to where I might start looking for a solution? Is it possible that my gradle build is doing something re the Service & callback?

I've not posted the code as it's unlikely to be the issue as it's working elsewhere.. I can post the LogCat logs if needed..

Thanks!

LOG CAT Using Service: my Tags are MJC and BTLE

```
10527-10527/ D/BTLE DE: IN MAIN ACTIVITY 
      AFTER LOAD tagUUID: 0BB14465-A514-4966-A6E0-0096201E22GG

 10527-10635/ D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true

 10527-10635/ I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: 
       QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
       I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

 10527-10527/ D/BTLE Svc :: BTLE Service Started

 10527-10527/ D/BTLE Svc :: onStartCommand : 
       INPARAM UUID: 0BB18329-A514-4944-A6e0-0096201E33EE

 10527-10527/ D/MJC onStartCommand: inside build version check

 10527-10527/ D/MJC scanLeDevice: start scanLeDevice

 10527-10527/ D/MJC scanLeDevice: START scan

 10527-10527/ D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON

 10527-10538/ D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5

 10527-10527/ D/MJC onStartCommand: scan device called

 10527-10635/ V/RenderScript: 0xa0b29000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4

 10527-10527/ D/MJC scanLeDevice: inside STOP scan

 10527-10527/ D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON

 10527-10527/ D/BTLE Svc :: BTLE Service Stopped
```

Comment: Hi Stanly, I've edited my answer with my log cat. I cant find info on the onClientRegistered results anywhere, do you know what that is?

Comment: and here are the logs when I run it in an activity.... Thanks for having a look for me!     http://pastebin.com/5TuY6nyF

Comment: OK. So diagnostically I have used another device to hook up to my IDe at home and again the app works perfectly. Having done this it can now only be my phone that is at fault. It runs well in an Activity but not when the same code is in a Service. Are there Developer settings that could be affecting my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, So I managed to solve my issue by reinstalling Android 6 again on my Nexus 5, but this time I didn't allow any extra apps to be installed (Facebook, Outlook GOW etc). When I ran my application again it responded properly and the Service callback worked well.

Currently I don't know if any of my normal apps were blocking or interfering with my applications Service, it seems unlikely. However, I will install them on at a time and test my application and report back if I get the same issue.

It's not much of an answer I'm afraid, but that's the nature of the beast.